# Vertical vector space = tangent space to a fiber

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces

Lee's *Introduction to Riemannian manifolds (2nd ed.)* introduces the vertical tangent vector space as follows (Page 21):

Here, $\tilde{M}_p = \pi^{-1}(p)$ for $p\in M$.

> Suppose $\tilde{M}$ and $M$ are smooth manifolds, $\pi:\tilde{M}\to M$
> is a smooth submersion, ..., At each point $x\in \tilde{M}$, we define
> two subspaces of the tangent space $T_x \tilde{M}$ as follows: **the
> vertical tangent space at $x$** is $\begin{equation} V_x =
>  \textrm{Ker}(d\pi_x) = T_x(\tilde{M}_{\pi(x)})\tag*{}\end{equation}$
> (that is, the tangent space to the fiber containing $x$). (The
> definition for the horizontal tangent space follows.)

The question is that I don't understand why $\textrm{Ker}(d\pi_x) = T_x(\tilde{M}_{\pi(x)})$ is true. Since the book does not give proof, the following is my attempt.

**My attempt**
Suppose $x\in \tilde{M}$.
Let's first prove $T_x(\tilde{M}_{\pi(x)})\subset \textrm{Ker}(d\pi_x)$. For any $v\in T_x(\tilde{M}_{\pi(x)})$, take a smooth curve $\gamma:[0,1]\to \tilde{M}_{\pi(x)}$  such that $\gamma(0)=x, \gamma'(0)=v$. Then, by definition of $M_{\pi(x)}=\pi^{-1}(\pi(x))$, we have $\pi\circ \gamma(t)=\pi(x)$ i.e. $\pi \circ \gamma$ is a constant curve on $M$. This implies that $(\pi\circ \gamma)'(0) = d\pi_{x}(\gamma'(0))  =d\pi_{x}(v)=0$, so $v\in \textrm{ker}(d\pi_x)$.

I do not know how to prove the other direction.

---

I have doubts even about the partial proof above. How do we know about the existence of a smooth curve $\gamma$ on $\tilde{M}_{\pi(x)}$ such that $\gamma(0)=x, \gamma'(0)=v$. How do we construct it?

Comment: Take a look at Proposition A.28 in Appendix A of IRM.